# GCC 2.9 and "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c, gcc

I have been playing around with void pointers and created this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct intint {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct intshortshort {
    int a;
    short b;
    short c;
};

void fill_me(struct intint **pii, void *piss)
{
    (void*)*pii = piss;                // Question about this line?
}

int main()
{
    struct intint *pii = NULL;
    struct intshortshort iss;
    iss.a = iss.b = iss.c = 13;

    fill_me(&pii, &iss);

    printf("%d..%d\n", pii->a, pii->b);


    return 0;
}
```

Question:

When I'm using gcc version 2.95.4 everything compiles and works as expected, but gcc version 4.7.3 gives me following error:

```
void_pointer.c:16:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Is there a reason why adding (void *) to lvalue is not allowed anymore?

**Edit:** Thank you for answers, I think I understood the problem, but the question **"why it was ok in the first place?"** is still interesting.

Comment: The result of a cast is not an lvalue unless it's to a reference. For example, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61ba4d86f65eaa3e

Comment: @chris No, the result of a cast is not an lvalue period. You may be thinking of another programming language.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, Forgive me, I thought this was tagged C++ when I made that comment. I'm pretty sure I'm just being insane.

Comment: @chris It is possible that it has been tagged C++ shortly. StackOverflow does something strange with edits done a very short time after posting.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, Yes, edits within five minutes of posting aren't logged separately, but I think I'm just crazy on this one.

Answer (score 3):

This question isn't about the `void*`, is about typecast and lvalue.

for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    (int)n = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

this code will causes same error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

That because the `=` operator requires a modifiable-lvalue as its left operand.

So, what is the `lvalue`? and what's the `modifiable-lvalue`? Please see [wikipedia:Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work for the same reason as why

```
  int x, y;
  (int)x = y;
```

doesn't work. The result of a cast is not a "lvalue", it does not hold a memory location where you can store something inside. Rather regard the result of `(int)x` as a temporary, invisible variable, which only exists during the execution of this operation.

Answer (score 2):

The old compiler(old version gcc) may allow cast-as-lvalue, but it ha been removed in the new version, you can find it [The cast-as-lvalue, conditional-expression-as-lvalue and compound-expression-as-lvalue extensions, which were deprecated in 3.3.4 and 3.4, have been removed.](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.0/changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use cast operator on the left operand of the assignment operator in C.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to cast to a `void**` and then dereference it:

```
void fill_me(struct intint **pii, void*piss)
{
        *(void **)pii=piss;
}
```

Output, as expected:

```
13..851981

13 is obvious
851,981 - 13 = 851,968
851,968 / (256*256) = 13
there are the 2 shorts as an int
```

Comment: @GintsDev Is this what you were trying to do?

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but I was looking more for a reason why earlier gcc versions didn't have an error.

Comment: @GintsDev Wasn't clear if you wanted something that worked, or wanted to know what changed, anyways this will work :)