# Compile error :lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I am a beginner in Linux and C together.
I need to run a program that I downloaded, in readme file was written that run "make" to build it`s running package. But when I ran it, I got these errors:

```
~/injectso-0.2$ make
gcc -I./  -c -g -O2 -Wall  procdbg.c
procdbg.c: In function ‘push_stack_proc’:
procdbg.c:149:26: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    (unsigned long) pvEsp -= iSize;
                          ^

procdbg.c: In function ‘restore_syscall’:
procdbg.c:244:49: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
          (unsigned long) ptProcStatus->regs.eip = (unsigned long) ptProcStatus->regs.eip - 2; 
                                                 ^
make: *** [procdbg.o] Error 1
```

It seems that the casting is wrong and makes the left hand of assignment to a value except for address. This is the actual code for first error:

```
   void *pvEsp;
   SProcStatus tProcStatus;

   /* If there is no data to be pushed, exit                               */
   if (!iSize)
      return(0);

   /* Get the current ESP                                                  */
   read_status(&(tProcStatus));
   pvEsp = (void *) SP(tProcStatus);

   show_debug(3, "Current ESP is %p\n", pvEsp);

   /* Now subtract the amount of space we need for the                     */
   /* data to be pushed                                                    */
   (unsigned long) pvEsp -= iSize;
```

I changed the faulty line to the bottom but the error still arises:

```
       (unsigned long *) pvEsp -= iSize;
```

Any suggestion you have?
And I have ubuntu 14.04 i686 on VMware.

### EDIT :

problem is solved from a patch that is in link in Slugonamission answer:

```
-   (unsigned long) pvEsp -= iSize;
+   pvEsp -= (unsigned long) iSize;
```

and

```
- (unsigned long) ptProcStatus->regs.eip = (unsigned long) ptProcStatus->regs.eip - 2; 
+  ptProcStatus->regs.eip = (unsigned long) ptProcStatus->regs.eip - 2;
```

But for people who wanted more information about problem, I personally dont know much about it but show you complete code of function:

```
 /* Write a saved eip into the remote process, this                      */
   /* address must NOT be a valid page (i.e it MUST cause                  */
   /* a segfault). For fun we use 0x41414140 (not 41414141                 */
   /* since its nice to have an aligned address)                           */
   pvEip = (void *) 0x41414140;
#if OS_LINUX && CPU_IA32
   push_stack_proc(&pvEip, sizeof(pvEip));
.....



/* push_stack_proc - Push specified data onto the remote                   */
/* stack                                                                   */
void *push_stack_proc(void *pvAddr, int iSize) {
   void *pvEsp;
   SProcStatus tProcStatus;

   /* If there is no data to be pushed, exit                               */
   if (!iSize)
      return(0);

   /* Get the current ESP                                                  */
   read_status(&(tProcStatus));
   pvEsp = (void *) SP(tProcStatus);

   show_debug(3, "Current ESP is %p\n", pvEsp);

   /* Now subtract the amount of space we need for the                     */
   /* data to be pushed                                                    */
    pvEsp -= (unsigned long) iSize;                   //correct line
  //((unsigned long ) pvEsp) -= iSize;                //faulty line

   /* Round it to a multiple of 8 (if it isn't already)                    */
   /* (We use 8 since Sparc requires double word alignment)                */
   pvEsp = (void *) round_down((unsigned long) pvEsp, STACK_ALIGN);

   /* Write the ESP to the process                                         */
   SP(tProcStatus) = (unsigned long) pvEsp;
   if (!write_regs(&(tProcStatus)))
      show_abort("Could not modify stack pointer in target process\n");
   read_status(&(tProcStatus));
   show_debug(3, "New SP is 0x%08x\n", SP(tProcStatus));

   /* Now write the data itself to the remote process                      */
   if (iSize > (write_proc(pvEsp, pvAddr, iSize)))
      show_abort("Could not write to remote process\n");

   return(pvEsp);
}
```

Comment: This looks like there is a `*` missing. Code which has been released with such simple faults I suspicious to me. I'd rethink using it without proper knowledege&review.

Comment: Ancient GCC 2.9 allowed non-standard `(type) var = value;` constructs. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675646/gcc-2-9-and-lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment . Nowdays it does not allow this kind of things. Maybe this source must be compiled with very old GCC?

Comment: Maybe `pvEsp = (char *)pvEsp - iSize;` is what you want, for the first one.  It would help if you could explain what effect you want the code to have.  For the second one it depends on what the type of `ptProcStatus->regs.eip` is.

Comment: @Olaf good idea! Beside this, when i wanted to download it from packetstorm, my browser alert about it but i thought its because of it`s functionality. And download it from another site and no alert shows to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your solution will change the semantics of the program (although it's hard to say which is correct without knowing what `isize` is or refers to), e.g.

```
int foo = 32;
foo = (unsigned long)foo - 5; // 27
foo = (unsigned long*)foo - 2; // will subtract 2*(sizeof(unsigned long*))
```

The result of a cast is not an lvalue and cannot be assigned to, and should be rewritten to instead cast back to the original value, e.g.

```
pvEsp = (void*)((unsigned long)pvPsp - iSize);
```

In C, the cast back to `void*` can be omitted and is implicit without warnings.

In addition, the Gentoo devs seem to have a patch that fixes this, as can be found here: https://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/dev-util/injectso/files/injectso-0.2-gcc4.patch

Comment: thanks for patch link, it is corrected . But i didnt get what happens in your example!(subtract 2*(size...)) can you give a reference about it.

Comment: @qwrt747 - I don't really have a general reference for it, but you need to look up how pointer arithmetic works; adding `1` to a pointer will increment the pointer to point at the "next" data value, so will logically add on the size of the data being pointed to rather than the next byte.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from your code snippet and error that `iSize` is a value not an address and `pvEsp` is an address. Change the faulty line as below, it should  solve the  compilation error-

```
*(unsigned long *) pvEsp -= iSize;
```

Comment: it seems by your solution also it solved,(at least in compile time). I dont know whether it logically is function or not. thanks